# How to store data from scanner to Firebase Realtime database Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to print the data from the scanner to firebase realtime database using Flutter. I am scanning a barcode pdf417 and I am printing it in a listview and now I want to store that data to firebase realtime database using a button.

I am using the Flutter library https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scanner as a reference.

May I please have assistance with this, I will post my code below.
Thank you for your assistance in advance.

```dart
body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            previewView,
            //printing scanned results
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return BarcodeItemWidget(preview.barcodeItems[position]);


                },
                itemCount: preview.barcodeItems.length,

              ),

            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('Save',),
              onPressed: () {

                // Map<String, dynamic> scaneditem = {
                //   "ScannedItem": BarcodeItemWidget,
                //   "Created On": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                // };
                // FirebaseFirestore.instance
                //     .collection("product")
                //     .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                //     .set(scaneditem);
                // print(scaneditem);
                databaseRef.push().set({'ScannedItem': preview.barcodeItems,});

              },
            ),
          ],
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm that your databaseRef has `.child('xxx')`

```
final DatabaseReference databaseRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('YOUR CHILD');
// confirm that your databaseRef has .child('xxx')
```

As pointed out by a GCP expert (Thank you). You should add the data as below:

```
databaseRef.push().set({
  'ScannedItem': preview.barcodeItems
      .map((barCodeItem) => barCodeItem.toJson())
      .toList(),
});
```

This is because `preview.barcodeItems` is actually a `List<BarcodeItem>`
object which can't be sent to the RTDB. It has a `.toJson()` method which
helps convert it to json which can then be sent."

Comment: Hi Peter, can you please explain more on what you mean? like what do I put on ('YOUR CHILD')?

Comment: The JSON document inside your Realtime Database that you want to add `scannedItem` to.

Comment: Hi Peter, I am getting this error after editing using your code:                                                              'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead'

Comment: Hi Peter I found the solution, I just edited your code like this and it worked:                                              databaseRef.push().set({
              'ScannedItem': preview.barcodeItems
                  .map((barCodeItem) => barCodeItem.toJson())
                  .toString(),
            });

Comment: I want to ask, one last thing, now how can I retrieve that Information from the database and print it out in a listview?